# Semantic relation between shape and text or image

Tags: dom, svg

I have an SVG image with lots of shapes, mostly rectangles. Each of these has a thumbnail image, caption text, and a mouseover tooltip associated with it.

However, for the image and caption, the "association" is only a visual one caused by me positioning them over the associated shape.

If a user clicks on a shape, how can the event handler make the same association, i.e. find the corresponding elements representing the image and captions?

I would naively have expected some sort of nested hierarchy, as with HTML, but clearly that's illegal in SVG except for the tooltip, e.g.

```
<style>
text {
    text-anchor: middle;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "Times New Roman";
    pointer-events: none;
}

rect {
    stroke: black;
    opacity: 0.6;
    stroke-width: 1.5;
    fill: lightblue;
}
</style>

<rect x="50" y="50" height="80" width="80">
<title>Tooltip for rectangle
</title>
<text x="90" y="100" dy="1.1em">Caption L1</text>
<text x="90" y="100" dy="2.2em">Caption L2</text>
<image x="51" y="51" width="78" height="50" xlink:href="https://example/thumbnail.jpg"/>
</rect>
```

Is there an efficient way of achieving this? Must every element have explicit id or class attributes, or must I put every instance into the defs section as a distinct group? There could be several hundred of these shapes.

Comment: put the things you want to group in a <g> element perhaps? Not sure what you mean about defs section in your question.

Comment: @RobertLongson, I was only suggesting the the <g> group would be in the <defs> section. If every single shape (with its caption and image) becomes a distinct group, is that efficient? I already employ groups for reusable shapes, so can one group reference another?

Comment: I don't really understand your comment I'm afraid.

Comment: @RobertLongson, I already have a <g> encompassing code that I use for clickable subregions of the shape (thus behaving like buttons). I tried your suggestion, and it seems good -- except that <title> tooltips only work in the <use> that references to the group; ones defined in the group are not seen. In other words, using a group for each of these instances seems to restrict me to just one tooltip for the whole group. Is that correct?

Comment: Perhaps you should update the question with your new markup.

Comment: Sorry, I'm being a bit slow today. Ignore my last comments. I tried the <g> as you suggested (outside of <defs>) and I think it works OK. Apologies for dragging out what was a simple answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution was provided by Robert Longson. I'm just making it explicit in case anyone else has the same requirement.

```
<g id="test">
<rect x="50" y="50" height="80" width="80">
<title>Tooltip for rectangle</title>
</rect>
<text x="90" y="100" dy="1.1em">Caption L1</text>
<text x="90" y="100" dy="2.2em">Caption L2</text>
<image x="51" y="51" width="78" height="50" xlink:href="https://example/thumbnail.jpg">
<title>Tooltip for image</title>
</image>
</g>
```

This seems to preserve tooltips and event-handling on separate elements, and provides a single enclosing element (with a distinct id) that provides the semantic grouping.